# How to get Python to make new lines in a print statement with \r\n?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now, I'm coding a python SMTP script.

```
status = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print (status)
```

When python prints `status`, I get:

```
b'250-mx.google.com at your service, [107.216.175.252]\r\n250-SIZE 35882577\r\n250-8BITMIME\r\n250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN\r\n250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n250 CHUNKING\r\n'
```

However, I want python to turn `\r\n` into the actual new lines and not just print it out as one giant line. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `print(str(status))`?

Comment: That doesn't work (or it's just me?)

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert byte array to Python string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-byte-array-to-python-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`status` has bytes type, so you need to decode it to string.

2 obvious ways to achieve this:

1. `print(status.decode())`
2. `print(str(status, 'utf-8'))`

The default encoding for [`.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) is UTF-8, so if you want to use a different one, do `status.decode(encoding)`.
 And `status.decode(encoding)` is exact equivalent to `str(status, encoding)`.

**Why just `str(status)` isn't working:**

From the [documentation on `str` function](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str):

Passing a bytes object to str() without the encoding or errors
arguments falls under the first case of returning the informal string
representation. For example:

```
>>> str(b'Zoot!')
"b'Zoot!'"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print(status.decode())
250-mx.google.com at your service, [107.216.175.252]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING
```

You're on Python 3 which defaults to unicode, but you have an old style byte-string from doing sockets. You just have to `decode` it and then the `print` will get rid of newline representations as usual.

Comment: What is "old style" about byte strings? They have their use, and they'll always have their use.

Comment: The fact that they were the default in Python 2 and no longer are in Python 3. Counter-question: what about being old implies being useless? (I still use "tar", the "**tape archiver**" every day. It's 30 years old and still works just fine.)